# Hide or Mask query parameters of a URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have to pass the username and password to a url in javascript as query string. I am using window.open() method. I am able to see the username and password in the url I am opening. I need to hide/mask the password how can i do that?

Note: I do not want to use post method form submit.

Comment: Not a good choice to send passwords over GET. But you should encrypt the password before sending and decrypt it back.

Answer (score -2):

```
window.open('http://google.com','_blank','location=no');
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

For the record... definitely a ***BAD*** idea.

Also, you might want to consider doing this using SSL. The HTTPS protocol also encrypts the querystring during transmission so this will also help with the MITM attacks of your **exposed credentials!!**

** Edit - of the modern browsers available, this will work in IE9 (as I discovered using MS CRM 2011). Other browsers mark the location bar as read-only instead but still display it as an anti-phishing mechanism as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: That won't work. Modern browsers do not support `location=no` as an anti-phishing measure.